# I want to calculate are of parallelogram only if vertices lie between 0 to 1000 ,i.e. 0<=x<1000. How can I define constraints?

Tags: python, data-science

How can I define constraints in python? I want to calculate are of parallelogram only if vertices lie between 0 to 1000 ,i.e. 0<=x<1000.

Comment: Your question lacks details. Can you provide more context and your own attempt at coding? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Vertices lie between 0 and 1000 on what? x axis or y axis?

Comment: What form is your data in? Are they lists, tuples or arrays or coordinates or the Xs and Ys separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the best method is to throw an exception inside your function.
For example :

```
def yourFunction(x):
    if(0<=x<1000):
        raise SyntaxError("Please provide a correct value")
    pass # your code here
```